# google map view change auto behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, web, react-google-maps

I an using 'react-google-maps' for rendering google map in my react app.

Everything works fine, except for some location like (37°32'01.6"N 77°27'23.4"W - Tomb of James Monroe) when we keep on zooming, the 2D view automatically changes to 3D like view (45 deg)

I can revert to old view by clicking a grid option in the bottom right corner of the view but thats not what I want.

[link to the image showing both view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEiKA.png)

Is there a prop to suppress this default behaviour. May be this is not related to react wrapper but your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Note: when view is transformed, the pin annotation kind of deviates away from actual location.

Answer (score 0):

Set `tilt` to zero.

```
<GoogleMap
   tilt={0}
   ...>
  ...
```